# "rst2html: command not found" after installing docutils?

Tags: mac, path

I've installed docutils on my Mac OS system following the [docutils instruction](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/README.html#gnu-linux-bsds-unix-mac-os-x-etc)s.

I've also done:

```
$ sudo cp tools/buildhtml.py tools/rst2html.py /usr/local/bin
```

However, if I open a command line and type `rst2html`, I get 'command not found'.

If I type `rst2html.py`, there's no problem, so the Python file itself is on my path.

How do I get my system to recognize `rst2html` as a valid command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about mac, but generally in a Unix system the file extension isn't implied. Indeed a file name extension rarely has any special meaning at all. However there are lot of Unix tricks to help you, perhaps creating a symbolic link:

```
$ sudo ln -s rst2html.py /usr/local/bin/rst2html
```

Answer (score 2):

When you type the command `rst2html` on the command line, it's going to look for a program called rst2html (not rst2html.somethingorother) in the directories in your PATH.  If you want `rst2html` to work, you need a file named rst2html.  There are several ways to do this:

1. Rename the program.  There's no actual need for the .py extension, as the system knows it's a Python script because of its [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/local/bin/rst2html.py /usr/local/bin/rst2html
   ```
2. Hard-link the program.  You can have the program listed in /usr/local/bin under two different names, rst2html.py and rst2html, and either one can be used to launch it.

   ```
   sudo ln /usr/local/bin/rst2html.py /usr/local/bin/rst2html
   ```
3. Symbolic-link the program.  Similar to hard-linking, except that only one is the "real" file, the other is just a unix-style alias.  This may be a bit easier to manage than hard-linking, because if you ever install an updated version, the link will automatically use the new version (while with a hard link, you'd need to update the link manually).

   ```
   sudo ln -s rst2html.py /usr/local/bin/rst2html
   ```

Personally, I'd just rename it (option 1), but either of the other options should work fine as well.